# How To Undo check-out and discard changes to a file grammatically?

Tags: check-out, check-in

If you check out a file from a library on a site, make changes, and then decide you don't want to keep the changes that you made, you can undo the check-out. The changes that you made to the file since you checked it out are discarded, and the file is made available again for other people to edit.

now,  want to do same thing bur grammatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SPFile.UndoCheckOut` to discard the changes.

Comment: Hi nadeem Will this Function Override The Checkout Done By Another User?

Comment: @AXAY, it will not override the checkout of the other user if the user performing it is not an admin user. For this you may need to run the code using `RunWithElevatedPreviliges`